# php curl api метод

Tags: php, curl, soap

Здравствуйте! Подскажите,пожалуйста, как задать метод(InfoCard) в запросе

Пишу его через  таким образом  $url =*****/InfoCard; Выдает не ошибку api, а вот этакое 
" soap:Client Неизвестная ошибка. Ошибка разбора XML: - [1,1] Фатальная ошибка: Document is empty по причине: Ошибка разбора XML: - [1,1] Фатальная ошибка: Document is empty "

```
    $url =*****/InfoCard;
    $xml = [
        'FirstData' => '20120101',
        'LastData' => '20220101',
        'INN' => '3202010293',
        'Nom' => '72',
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($xml),
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Ну так в ошибке вам как раз и говорят что Ошибка разбора XML, то есть если вы объявляете в хедере запроса что отправляете xml, то и отправляйте xml, а не просто форму, кто за вас xml то формировать будет?

Comment: убрал - тоже самое

Comment: А XML добавили?

Comment: сказали там принимают строку а не xml

Comment: вообще метод в url прописывается?

Comment: Если у Вас SOAP, то и работайте с ним как с [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.soapclient.php)

Comment: Сказали `Ошибка разбора XML`

Comment: Антон, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. это SOAP, то сервер должен предоставлять WSDL. И тогда работа с ним будет выглядеть так

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://....../server.wsdl");
$client->InfoCard(
  new SoapParam('20120101', 'FirstData'),
  new SoapParam('20220101', 'LastData'),
  new SoapParam('3202010293', 'INN'),
  new SoapParam('72', 'Nom'),
);
```